# RequestDispatcher can't forward to a resource in WEB-INF

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

Developing small sample BookStore application and have a problem.

In the screenshot I got WEB-INF/pages/book-form.jsp and when I use below line in 
doGet servlet method like

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/book-form.jsp").forward(req, res);
```

can not find the page BUT if I use

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/book-form.jsp").forward(req, res);
```

which is working fine.

**Question:** How to resolve "/WEB-INF/pages/book-form.jsp"?

[image: BookStore Application]

Comment: What's the exact error message and stack trace of the exception you get? Which container are you using?

Comment: I would guess OP is using Tomcat 7 (see Libraries) ;)

Comment: Looks fine so far. What Tomcat 7 version exactly are you using? What if you use `request.getRequestDispatcher(...)` instead? (which is also the normal practice by the way)

Comment: @balusc, apache-tomcat-7.0.27. I changed to JBoss and the same code working. Why its not working in Tomcat. Any idea?

Comment: What if you use `request.getRequestDispatcher(...)` instead? (which is also the normal practice by the way)

Comment: I got the same issue when using the JBoss EAP6.4